# Fragment menu not opening new activity

Tags: android, android-fragments

Kindly check below code

```
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    public class AndroidTabLayoutActivity extends TabActivity implements OnTabChangeListener {
        TabHost tabHost;
        TabWidget tabWidget;
        Menu menu;
        View v;

        /** Called when the activity is first created. */
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.main);
            tabWidget = getTabWidget();
            tabHost = getTabHost();
            tabHost.setOnTabChangedListener(this);

            TabSpec eventbyspec = tabHost.newTabSpec("EventBy");
            // eventbyspec.setIndicator("EventBy",
            // getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.icon_photos_tab));
            eventbyspec.setIndicator("EventBy");
            Intent eventbyIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
            eventbyspec.setContent(eventbyIntent);

            // Tab for category
            TabSpec categoryspec = tabHost.newTabSpec("Category");
            categoryspec.setIndicator("Category");
            Intent categoryIntent = new Intent(this, CatagoryEvent.class);
            categoryspec.setContent(categoryIntent);


            // Adding all TabSpec to TabHost
            tabHost.addTab(eventbyspec); // Adding eventby tab
            tabHost.addTab(categoryspec); // Adding category tab    
        }


        @Override
        public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
               MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
               int tab = getTabHost().getCurrentTab();

               if (tab==1)
                   inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu); 
               return true;
            }

        @Override
        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

            switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.music:
                // Single menu item is selected do something
                // Ex: launching new activity/screen or show alert message
                Intent music_intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MusicFragment.class);
                startActivity(music_intent);
                return true;
            case R.id.theatre:
                Intent music_intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),TheatreFragment.class);
                startActivity(music_intent);
                return true;

            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
            }
        }

    }
```

Where MusicFragment.java is

```
                public class MusicFragment extends Fragment implements OnClickListener {

        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setHasOptionsMenu(true);
        }
        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.music_layout, container, false);
            LinearLayout mLayout = (LinearLayout) v
                    .findViewById(R.id.catagory_linearlayout);

            mLayout.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.music_full);
            TableLayout tableLayout = (TableLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.maintable);
            tableLayout.removeAllViews();
            for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {

                TableRow tableRow = new TableRow(v.getContext());
                tableRow.setPadding(10, 10, 10, 10);
                tableRow.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
                        LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

                TextView tv = new TextView(v.getContext());
                tv.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.black_overlay));

                tv.setText("random text here 11");


                tableRow.addView(tv);

                tv.setOnClickListener(this);


                tableLayout.addView(tableRow, new TableLayout.LayoutParams(
                        LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

            }
            return v;
        }

        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(), TextActivity.class));
        }

    }
```

and my CatagoryEvent.java is

```
    public class CatagoryEvent extends FragmentActivity {

        SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;
        ViewPager mViewPager;

        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.catagory_layout);      

            mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
            mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
            mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);
        }

        public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
            public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
                super(fm);
            }

             @Override
                public Fragment getItem(int position) {
                    Fragment fragment;
                    switch (position) {
                        case 0:
                            fragment = new MusicFragment();
                            break;
                        case 1:
                            fragment = new TheatreFragment();
                            break;                 
                        default:
                            fragment  = null;
                            break;
                    }
                    return fragment;

                }
            @Override
            public int getCount() {
                // Show 3 total pages.
                return 2;
            }       
            @Override
            public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
                Locale l = Locale.getDefault();
                switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    return getString("Music");
                case 1:
                    return getString("Theatre");

                }
                return null;
            }   
        }
    }
```

**PROBLEM**

Problem is on click menu item MusicFragment.java not called 
and asked to declare in androidmanifaste 
but can't declare it on androidmanifaste

Is there any way to call a fragment class from activity?

Comment: too much code, you can't expect anyone to read all this. Reduce the code to a minimal example producing the problem.

Answer (score 1):

No you can't. If you look at your code, you can already see the problem yourself: You use 'startActivity' to start a Fragment.

A Fragment needs to be hosted inside an Activity, to be able to live. You can however, just wrap this Fragment into an empty Activity, and call that Activity from your onClick instead.

Comment: de brujin I am a newbie and dont know how to wrapup this fragment.

Comment: You should really read up on the developers site on Fragments. They are at the very base of your app, and you will run into troubles if you do not set this up properly. It's very simple. You should read the official developer site of Google, or take some quick lessons at http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidFragments/article.html